# Unzip large files make my program shutting down

Tags: c#, file, io, zip, extract

I have some code which should unzip my zip files. I got a zip file:
[image: Zip file infos]

and each time i unzip it with my program, my program hangs and don't even give me a message or so.

my code:

```
public void CreateZipContentFolder(List<String> zips, string destinationPath) {
        if (zips.Any()) {
            MyLog.WriteToLog("Unzipping Zip files to: " + destinationPath, MyLog.Messages.Info);
            foreach (string zip in zips) {
                string dirName = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zip));

                //using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zip)) {
                  //  foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries) {
                    //    if (entry.FullName.EndsWith("/")) {
                      //      ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zip, destinationPath);
                        //    break;
                        //} else if (!Directory.Exists(dirName)) {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
                            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zip, dirName);
                  //          break;
                        //}
                    //}
                //}
            }
        } else { MyLog.WriteToLog("No Zip folders found.", MyLog.Messages.Warning); }
    }
```

Comment: Do any of the unzipped files get created?

Comment: Try debug step by step. Maybe your program doesn't hangs but just need some time to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess your program hangs because the method you call is a blocking one.
This means the method is doing work (extracting), cpu usage should be high.

An option to let your application still respond would be to call the ZIP methods inside a thread. So your UI could still respond, and it wouldn't look like your application is crashed.